# What is the data type and how to initialize it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

```
    
demos.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Contact',
    sorters: 'firstName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('firstName')[0];
    },  

    data: [
        {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Benesh'},
        {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Minich'},
        {firstName: 'Tania', lastName: 'Ricco'},
        {firstName: 'Odessa', lastName: 'Steuck'},
        {firstName: 'Nelson', lastName: 'Raber'},
        {firstName: 'Tyrone', lastName: 'Scannell'},
        {firstName: 'Allan', lastName: 'Disbrow'},
        {firstName: 'Cody', lastName: 'Herrell'},
        {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Burgoyne'},
        {firstName: 'Jessie', lastName: 'Boedeker'},
        {firstName: 'Allan', lastName: 'Leyendecker'},
        {firstName: 'Javier', lastName: 'Lockley'},
        {firstName: 'Guy', lastName: 'Reasor'},
        ...,
        ...
        ]
})
```

In my understanding, "data" is not dictionary or array type of javascript.
Is this kind of data type additionally supported by jQuery?

My questions are:

1. What is the type of parameter of Ext.data.Store(...)?
2. Also, the type of data?
3. In this case, how can I dynamically init the data?
   (I have a lot of data, so static assignment is not desirable.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a watch on it in firebug and debug the javascript

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by "dynamically init the data".  Also, I think the typeof operator might help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What is the type of parameter of Ext.data.Store(...)?

It's just a plain object with a bunch of properties being used as an associative array.  Pretty much all function arguments in Ext JS are passed in using a single object like this.  In Ext JS terms, they call this a "configuration object".

> 2) Also, the type of data?

Data is a array.  Each element of the array is an object with a bunch of properties used as an associative array, similar to the parameter of `Ext.data.Store()`.

> 3) In this case, how can I dynamically init the data?

You can declare an empty array to start and add it to your configuration object.  Then declare each row separately and push them into that array, finally use the configuration object when you call new `Ext.data.Store()`.

Hopefully these code samples will be self-explanatory.

```
var cfg = new Object(); // same as var cfg = {};
cfg.model = "Contact"; // one way to set a property
cfg["sorters"] = "firstName"; // another way to set a property

// one way to set the function
cfg.getGroupString = function(record) {
  return record.get('firstName')[0];
};

// here's another way to set the function
function myGetGroupString(record) {
  return record.get('firstName')[0];
}
cfg.getGroupString = myGetGroupString;

// initializing data long-hand
cfg.data = new Array(); // same as cfg.data = [];
var record1 = new Object();
record1.firstName = "Mike";
record1.lastName = "Lin";
cfg.data.push(record1);

// another way to define a record
var record2 = {firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Mraz"};
cfg.data.push(record2);

// cfg is just a plain old object used as an associative array/hash
demos.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store(cfg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is taking one parameter and is a javascript Object type.

```
  {
    model: 'Contact',
    sorters: 'firstName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('firstName')[0];
    },
    data: [ ... ] ;
  }
```

This can directly be associated to a variable and then passed as parameter too.

```
var param1 = {
        model: 'Contact',
        sorters: 'firstName',
        getGroupString : function(record) {
            return record.get('firstName')[0];
        },
        data: [ ... ]
      }
```

The data is a variable in param1 object which contains array of javascript objects.

Comment: That's a single object parameter to the function. You probably got thrown off by the fact that the object's getGroupString member is actually a function. That closing brace actually has a matching opening brace that isn't the beginning of the object declaration. The functional call is syntactically valid.

Comment: @Ithibodeaux - Yes. Little late realization but edited my answer already to reflect the actual answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you initialize it as a empty object and then fill it afterwards with your content?

Anyway: 
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#cls-Ext.data.Store

Answer (score 0):

The parameter passed to `Ext.data.Store()` is an object, a.k.a. a dictionary or associative array in other languages. The `data` property of this object (`data : [{…},…]` is a simple array filled with more objects.